# Error: Could not find or load main class test.class HELP please

Tags: class, program-entry-point

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

I try to run this in cmd on Windows 7 like this :

```
@echo off
cls
javac test.java
cls
java test.class
pause
```

and cmd returns: `Error: Could not find or load main class test.class`

thanks for reading

Comment: Which of the two commands in your batch file is failing?

Comment: When running a class via `java`, omit the `.class`.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your file, it means you know the class name should be same with it's file name. you did not use any package in your code file, first of all you should change the command prompt path to the folder that your code file is in it.

for example your file is in C:\javalab folder. first you should change the path:
C:> cd javalab
and then:
C:\javalab> java test.class

if you use a package, the test.java file should be in the path that you demonstrate in front of the package keyword.

for example the package is:
package com.org.prog;
the file should be in com\org\prog folder. change the command prompt path before the org folder and enter the java command:
java com.org.prog.test

be careful the command prompt path should be back of the org folder before you enter java command to run test.class.

be successful.